# How can I display an Emgu CV imagebox programmatically in a WPF application

Tags: wpf, emgucv

I have already created an imagebox via WindowsFormsHost that is able to display the depth image of a Intel Realsense camera. But now I need to create a second imagebox programmatically via Emgu CVs API so that I can move it for example between screens.

Is this possible?

Here is my XAML Code for the Main Window so far:

```
<Window x:Class="Intel.RealSense.CaptureWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Intel.RealSense"
        xmlns:WinFormsCtrl1="clr-namespace:Emgu.CV.UI;assembly=Emgu.CV.Platform.NetFramework"
        mc:Ignorable="d" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
        Closing="control_Closing"
        Title="Intel RealSense Calibration Tool" Height="700" Width="1200" x:Name="control">

    <Grid Margin="10,0,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="txtTimeStamp" Grid.Column="0" />

        <WindowsFormsHost Grid.Column="0">

            <WinFormsCtrl1:ImageBox x:Name="imgBox1" />

        </WindowsFormsHost>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I know that via

```
 ImageBox pImgbox = new ImageBox();
```

I can create a new Imagebox, but how can I connect it to a WPF application without Windows Forms Host so that I can create an ImageBox window that I can move between screens.